# Extracting triples from text in php using Stanford-NLP?

Tags: php, owl, triples

I have a text .. I went to extract triples from text ..  I use Stanford-NLP Library in php  [Standford-NLP](https://github.com/agentile/PHP-Stanford-NLP) How can I extract triples(subject - object - predicate)?

The example code in the GitHub ReadMe shows how to write the code. The output is a list of word/part-of-speech pairs. Looking at the first example, 
"What does the fox say?" becomes:

```
 array(3) {
  ["wordsAndTags"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "What"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "WP"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "does"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "VBZ"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "the"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "DT"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "fox"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "NN"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "say"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "VB"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "?"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "."
    }
  }
  ["penn"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["parent"]=>
    string(4) "ROOT"
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["parent"]=>
        string(5) "SBARQ"
        ["children"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["parent"]=>
            string(4) "WHNP"
            ["children"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["parent"]=>
                string(7) "WP What"
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
              }
            }
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["parent"]=>
            string(2) "SQ"
            ["children"]=>
            array(3) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["parent"]=>
                string(8) "VBZ does"
                ["children"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
              }
              [1]=>
              array(2) {
                ["parent"]=>
                string(2) "NP"
                ["children"]=>
                array(2) {
                  [0]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["parent"]=>
                    string(6) "DT the"
                    ["children"]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                  }
                  [1]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["parent"]=>
                    string(6) "NN fox"
                    ["children"]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              [2]=>
              array(2) {
                ["parent"]=>
                string(2) "VP"
                ["children"]=>
                array(1) {
                  [0]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["parent"]=>
                    string(6) "VB say"
                    ["children"]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          [2]=>
          array(2) {
            ["parent"]=>
            string(3) ". ?"
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["typedDependencies"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "dobj"
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "say"
        ["index"]=>
        int(5)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(4) "What"
        ["index"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "aux"
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "say"
        ["index"]=>
        int(5)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(4) "does"
        ["index"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "det"
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "fox"
        ["index"]=>
        int(4)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "the"
        ["index"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "nsubj"
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "say"
        ["index"]=>
        int(5)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "fox"
        ["index"]=>
        int(4)
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "root"
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(4) "ROOT"
        ["index"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["feature"]=>
        string(3) "say"
        ["index"]=>
        int(5)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I need to extract triples .. How can I do that?

Comment: This post is a little vague, could you explain the general idea behind the rdf graph whose triples you hope to capture? Also do look at the rdf primer, it may help clear up your confusion http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-primer-20040210/